# "Seemed to had" is it correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Here's a sentence I made up:

"He seemed to had not understood what I had said to him"

Is this sentence correct? I tried searching for similar sentences by putting quotation marks around 'seemed to had not', and out popped roughly 5-6 results, but that doesn't seem to be that many, especially because some of those could've been mistakes, and I couldn't find any questions like this.

Also, assuming it is correct, if I change the position of 'not', like so:

"He seemed to not had understood what I had said to him"

Would it still be grammatical?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No matter where you put the "not", a statement with "to had" isn't grammatical. The construction you are using is "seem" + to-infinitive. The infinitive for the verb have/had is "to have", not "to had."

This is discussed in detail on the [BBC "Learning English" website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv353.shtml):

> **seem / appear to + infinitive**
>
> After **seem** and **appear** we often use a
>   **to + infinitive** construction ( or a **perfect infinitive** construction
>   for past events).
>   ...

So what you should say is either of:

1. He seemed not to have understood what I had said to him.
2. He seemed to have not understood what I had said to him.
3. He seemed to not have understood what I had said to him.

The "not" could really go in any of those 3 places, but the first possibility sounds smoother and more idiomatic. The last sentence sounds the least natural to me, even slightly awkward.

Comment: The word order in sentences 2 and 3 has only become acceptable in the last 2 or 3 decades.

Comment: @phoog: I don't think the sticklers ever objected to 2 particularly, though they certainly did to 3.

Comment: @ColinFine in my experience it's not so much about sticklers as just the sentences that people would actually say or write.

Comment: An additional formulation that would include the OP's use of "had not" would be "It seemed that he had not understood what I had said to him".

Answer (score 2):

No,

> He seemed to had not understood what I had said to him.

is not grammatical at all, and neither is your other construction.

Here's what you should use:

> He seemed not to have understood what I had said to him.

Comment: Could you explain why it's incorrect, if you don't mind of course.

Answer (score 1):

to has to be followed by a bare infinitive or perfect infinitive:

He seems to understand. [bare, present]

He seems to have understood. [perfect infinitive, past idea or tense]

The perfect infinitive is have + the past participle.